# Ubuntu Server 16 LTS no usb 2.0

Tags: hardware, usb, ubuntu-16.04

After installation **Ubuntu Server 16 LTS**, there is no usb 2.0.
I can not connect mouse, keyboard, disc, pendrive e.t.c.
On usb 3.0 it works.

Motherboard - new Gigabyte - GA-970A-DS3P

Comment: It seems that this is old problem with this motherboard and Ubuntu x64. After fast googling I found that the problem was fixed after ENABLING IOMMU in Bios.

Comment: Thank you for this, now everything works - usb 3, 2 and my Ethernet. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188370

Comment: This sounds good.I'll post it as an answer to give you a chance to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Enable** the **IOMMU** option in the **BIOS** setup